# ruby / Passing arguments to a dynamically created class

Tags: ruby, class, dynamic

There's probably many other better ways; but having the following piece of code :

```
class ApplicationService
  def self.build(*args, &block)
    new(*args, &block).build
  end
end

class BaseClass; end

class Fetcher < ApplicationService
  attr_reader :resource_name

  def initialize(resource_name)
    @resource_name = resource_name
  end

  def build
    resource_name = @resource_name

    Class.new(BaseClass) do
      @@resource_name = resource_name

      class << self
        def all
          "http://some.remote.resource/#{@@resource_name}/all"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

in order to have the initial `resource_name` in the `self.all` method, i came up with defining `@@resource_name = resource_name`. I'm totally unsure if that's the good way to go.

I'd like to be able to use such 'generator', in order to provide the following interface :

```
## In some kind of initializers :
Xyz = Fetcher.build('xyz')

## Final use :
Xyz.all
```

Would there be a better pattern to have the class created dynamically, while passing arguments when creating this class ?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just have `build` return an instance of `BaseClass`? You could move `all` to `BaseClass` and store resource_name as a regular instance variable there

Comment: @maxpleaner that'd be cleaner indeed. how would you pass `resource_name` to BaseClass ?

Comment: `BaseClass.new(resource_name)` or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear why you want to create the class in the first place. If there are good reasons for it, my answer is kind of invalid.

You can have the desired behaviour using "standard" OOP techniques and working with instances

```
class Fetcher
  def initialize(resource_name)
    @resource_name = resource_name
  end

  def all
    "http://some.remote.resource/#{@resource_name}/all"
  end
end

xyz_fetcher = Fetcher.new('xyz')
xyz_fetcher.all
```

Otherwise, your code is more or less what you would/should do, I guess. Just, I would let the `Fetcher` class act as a singleton (not use an instance of `Fetcher`):

```
class Fetcher < ApplicationService
  # make a singleton by privatizing initialize (read this up somewhere else)

  def self.build(resource_name)
    Class.new(BaseClass) do
      @@resource_name = resource_name

      class << self
        def all
          "http://some.remote.resource/#{@@resource_name}/all"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then

```
Xyz = Fetcher.build('xyz')
Xyz.all
```

Now, you have the stuff with `ApplicationService` which more or less achieves that (and passes a block), so probably we readers miss some parts of the bigger picture ... please clarify if that is the case.

Besides singletonization, you could also work with modules instead (thanks @max for the comment).

Comment: the picture is not that bigger as it is somehow just investigations about how classes works in details - graphql ruby introduced me to a dynamic class based structure; I was here simply looking around this approach with plain classes

Comment: about the first part of you reply; I do agree, no need to have such structure to achieve this simple goal. but again is was trying to see how it would behave in a dynamic context. Thx for the singleton pointer

Comment: If you want to make it non-instanciable then declare it as a module instead of a class.